# Using Excel index/match to search a column containing numbers and text

Tags: excel

I have 2 tables:

**tblCodes** contains 2 columns:

Code (4-char code can be text or numeric), Code Name (text description)

**tblSerialNum** contains 3 columns:

SerialNum column (can be text or numeric),

Code column is 1st 4 chars of SerialNum using LEFT() function,

Code Name column uses index/match to look up Code Name that matches Code:

=INDEX(tblCodes[Code Name],MATCH([@Code],tblCodes[Code],0))

[sample tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyvwS.png)

The problem is with the serial # 1234001:  the MATCH doesn't work when the Code is all numeric because the LEFT() function always returns a string "1234" and it doesn't find it in the code table because it reads as number 1234.

I can't convert the values in the tlbSerialNum[Code] column to numeric because some are text "x333".

I've tried formatting the tblCodes[Code] column to text, but the function still treats 1234 as numeric.

I can type '1234 into tblCodes[Code] using an apostrophe to force it as a text, but I don't want to rely on my users to always remember to enter it that way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change everything to text in the formula:

```
=INDEX(tblCodes[Code Name],MATCH([@Code]&"",tblCodes[Code]&"",0))
```

This is now an array formula and depending on one's version may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Beautiful!  I had tried to add &"" to the search range but did not realize it made it an array function which is why it didn't work for me.  Ctrl+Shift+Enter did the trick. Thanks!   BTW, does an array formula add a lot of overhead to the table vs. an in-line formula like I was using?  I have a several columns like this on a table >1000 rows used with a barcode scanner scanning in multiple lines in succession.

Comment: Yes, make sure you limit the ranges in the lookups to the smallest possible.